# Accessing USB port programmatically

Tags: python, usb

I was doing some work on MSP430 series MCU.
I have designed a GUI (using wxPython). Now I want to control microcontroller with GUI, but I can't find any modules in python that can send data to the USB port so that the microcontroller can identify it.

Does there exist any module that can send and receive data to/from  USB port?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[libusb](http://www.libusb.org) is what you're after. [PyUSB](https://github.com/walac/pyusb) may be worth taking a look at also.

Comment: It seems like PyUSB is dead

Comment: @ThomasKilian The project has moved to GitHub, I've updated the link. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, cool. I meanwhile used the link from the other answer successfully, but I'll have a look here too.

Answer (score 1):

Does the board expose a serial port over the USB? If so, I highly recommend [pyserial](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial).

Comment: This link shows how to use PySerial to talk to a Arduino: http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Python