# How to use Python to identify Usb drives and use them as Destination paths for copying files and directories

Tags: python, windows, copy, usb, external

Was wondering how I could implement python to assist me in copying files to/from different USB port devices. After trying to find a way to get the path of USB input devices I found that they are instance devices and therefore do not give paths. I saw something about PyUsb that could possibly aid in what i'm trying to accomplish, but I wanted to see if there were any better options. My end goal is to be able to write a script that all you need to do is plug in the destination paths and it should copy all of the contents from one drive to another. Please note that I am not asking for code but simply possible tools that could aid me as I try to put this project together myself! Please Advise!

Comment: not sure but this thread may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817026/accessing-usb-port-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're looking for some references to get yourself started, however you are asking on the wrong section of stack. You should be going to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) and posting your question over there using the proper tags. Stack Overflow is typically used when you already have found the resources you're going to use, and you've encountered an error when trying to create or implement something using them

But to get you started, I would suggest using [PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb) which is a python implementation of [LibUSB](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki)

Comment: I installed pyusb and libusb , however when trying to use them now im getting an import error. usb.core,  does not exist.

Comment: What's your exact line for when you're importing? Also, can you try to do the import on a python interactive terminal?

Comment: Hi wes, the exact line is import usb.core and sure, ill give it a shot

Comment: Can you do me a favor and see if any errors pop up if you do an `import usb`

Comment: Hi Wes, sorry for the late response, but I did try to import usb alone and I still come up with the error for some reason, I am going to try looking into the file installation and see if maybe something didnt go right. All of the pyusb modules are on my computer and they seem fine..not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hi Wes, after looked at the linked question down below, It seems like some folks have indicated the libusb or possibly pyserial are options. some have said that pyusb is no longer supported